# How to calculate $V^i \frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}\frac{2R^2u^j}{|u|^2+R^2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, soft-question, proof-explanation

This is part of the calculation from page 37 of Lee's Riemannian Manifolds where we are trying to prove that Stereographic projection is a conformal equivalence.

The book says:

$V^i \frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}\frac{2R^2u^j}{|u|^2+R^2}=\frac{2R^2V_j}{|u|^2+R^2} - \frac{4R^2u^j<V,u>}{(|u|^2+R^2)^2}$

Where $u=(u_1,....u_n,0) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $V(|u|^2)=2 \Sigma_k V^ku^k=2<V,u>$

I'm having problems getting from one side of the equality to the others... This is ultimately just the quotient rule, right? Can somebody help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what any of these terms mean, but it does appear to be a simple product rule type equation. The key thing that is absorbed into the notation is that $|u|^2$ is a function of $u_1,u_2,...,u_n$ and must be considered so for the derivatives.

Assuming $R$ is a constant, consider a lower dimensional example
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{1}{a^2+b^2+R^2} = -\frac{2 a}{(a^2+b^2+R^2)^2}
$$
so in the case where $i \ne j$, if $|u|^2=\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}=\langle u,u\rangle$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i} \frac{u^j}{|u|^2+R^2} = u^j\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i} \frac{1}{|u|^2+R^2} = -\frac{2 u^i u^j}{(|u|^2+R^2)^2}
$$
and
$$
V^i\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i} \frac{u^j}{|u|^2+R^2} = -\frac{2 V^i u^i u^j}{(|u|^2+R^2)^2}
$$
with the implied sum over $i$ ([Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)) this gives the inner product term
$$
V^i\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i} \frac{u^j}{|u|^2+R^2} = -\frac{2 \langle V,u\rangle u^j}{(|u|^2+R^2)^2}
$$
the origin of the other term is going to be solely from the case that $i=j$, which will invoke a product (or quotient, same thing) like rule. Consider:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial u^j} \frac{u^j}{|u|^2+R^2} = \frac{1}{|u|^2+R^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial u^j}u^j + u^j\frac{\partial}{\partial u^j}\frac{1}{|u|^2+R^2}
$$
the second term we know how to deal with as above, and is needed to contribute to the terms as before, in the first term here 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial u^j}u^j = 1
$$
but now the $V^i$ is definately a $V^j$ because it's the case where $i=j$. I don't know why the index dropped, it might be a typo, or perhaps this is some kind of contra-co-variant magic that I don't have the background to fully understand. Otherwise the $2R^2$ looks like a constant which will factor in.

Hope this helps!

Edit:

I think I see the raising and lowering of the index must be that $V^i$ is a row vector, and turns into a column vector $V_j$ after the product with the matrix of values.

Comment: Yeah man, thanks... Sometimes I can't see such obvious things for some reason!!!

Comment: @MSV Glad I could help. You'll see other things as obvious that others don't too!